# -Wconversion and implicit string to bool cast

Tags: c++

I got used to writing this idiom:

```cpp
assert(!"Something went wrong");
```

But now `-Wconversion` has been enabled in the project, and this code no longer compiles:

```
error: implicit conversion turns string literal into bool
```

I understand that if I cast it explicitly, the error will go away, but it is too cumbersome:

```cpp
assert(!static_cast<bool>("Something went wrong"));
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Write your own assertion macro?

Comment: Would this work?  `assert( ("Something went wrong", false) );` because the inner-expression uses the comma-operator to evaluate to `false`, while still maintaining your string-literal for readability?

Comment: @abelenky • probably would have to do `assert(((void)"Something went wrong", 0));` (either `0` or `false`, but `0` is shorter), or trip the other error about discarded values and comma operator.

Comment: @abelenky I like that, this can be an answer:-)

Comment: `inline bool operator""_fail(char const*, std::size_t) { return false; }` and then `assert("Something went wrong"_fail);` might be convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And my options, shorter than the other earlier answered:

```
assert(!"something went wrong"[0]);
assert(!*"something went wrong");
```

Comment: Nice, I like the second one!

Comment: @ivaigult Your one is also nice. Just wanted to add it, but you were first.

Answer (score 4):

This might work, depending on all your specific compiler settings:

```
assert( ("Something went wrong", false) );
```

The inner-expression uses the comma-operator to evaluate to false, while still maintaining your string-literal for readability.

You might be able to replace `false` with `0` for brevity as well.

Answer (score 4):

Another one I came up with:

```
assert(!&"Something went wrong");
```

This will work since `&"Something went wrong"` is an address of a constant string, which must be non null. And `!` will negate it, so, it's a `false`.

Answer (score 3):

If it needs to be plain `cassert`, I'd go with

```cpp
assert(0 && "something went wrong");
```

This should work due to short-circuiting of `&&` and `0` being "truthy" (implicitly convertible to bool).

Otherwise use a better assertion library in general, like [snowhouse](https://github.com/banditcpp/snowhouse) or [libassert](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/libassert)

Comment: Or `assert(0**"something went wrong");` = 0 to the power of "something went wrong" (in a pythonic way of thinking)

Answer (score 0):

The normal idiom for assert with a message is this:

```cpp
assert(condition_that_should_be_true && "something went wrong");
```

If you want to unconditionally fail, you can just make that condition `false`:

```cpp
assert(false && "something went wrong");
```

But note that you rarely need to do this. For example:

```cpp
if (!check_conditions()) assert(false && "something went wrong");
// Can simply be
assert(check_conditions() && "something went wrong");
```